# ImportError: Library "GLU" not found

Tags: python-3.x

On CentOS 7.5 system, run python3 and execute the following code:

```
import gym
import time
env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
observation = env.reset()
count = 0
for t in range(100):
    action = env.action_space.sample()
    observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
    if done: 
        break
    env.render()
    count+=1
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Report the following error after executing the above code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
  File "/root/gym/gym/core.py", line 284, in render
    return self.env.render(mode)
  File "/root/gym/gym/envs/classic_control/cartpole.py", line 106, in render
    from gym.envs.classic_control import rendering
  File "/root/gym/gym/envs/classic_control/rendering.py", line 25, in <module>
    reraise(prefix="Error occured while running `from pyglet.gl import *`",suffix="HINT: make sure you have OpenGL install. On Ubuntu, you can run 'apt-get install python-opengl'. If you're running on a server, you may need a virtual frame buffer; something like this should work: 'xvfb-run -s \"-screen 0 1400x900x24\" python <your_script.py>'")
  File "/root/gym/gym/utils/reraise.py", line 17, in reraise
    reraise_impl(e, traceback)
  File "/root/gym/gym/utils/reraise_impl_py3.py", line 4, in reraise_impl
    raise e.with_traceback(traceback) from None
  File "/root/gym/gym/envs/classic_control/rendering.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pyglet.gl import *
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/gymlab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/gl/__init__.py", line 100, in <module>
    from pyglet.gl.lib import GLException
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/gymlab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/gl/lib.py", line 143, in <module>
    from pyglet.gl.lib_glx import link_GL, link_GLU, link_GLX
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/gymlab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/gl/lib_glx.py", line 51, in <module>
    glu_lib = pyglet.lib.load_library('GLU')
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/gymlab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/lib.py", line 158, in load_library
    raise ImportError('Library "%s" not found.' % names[0])
gym.utils.reraise.ReraisedException: Error occured while running `from pyglet.gl import *`
```

The original exception was:

```
ImportError: Library "GLU" not found.

HINT: make sure you have OpenGL install. On Ubuntu, you can run 'apt-get install python-opengl'. If you're running on a server, you may need a virtual frame buffer; something like this should work: 'xvfb-run -s "-screen 0 1400x900x24" python <your_script.py>'
```

According to the error prompt, after installing OpenGL, the running code will still report the same error. The following is the process of installing OpenGL:

```
[root@devmaster ~]# yum -y install python-opengl
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.aliyun.com
 * extras: mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn
 * updates: ftp.iij.ad.jp
Package PyOpenGL-3.0.1-6.el7.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[root@devmaster ~]#
```

Comment: Have you install freeglut too?

Comment: I have installed freeglut。

    [root@devmaster gym]# yum -y install freeglut
    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
    Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
     * base: mirrors.aliyun.com
     * extras: mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn
     * updates: ftp.iij.ad.jp
    base          | 3.6 kB  00:00:00     
    code          | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
    extras        | 3.4 kB  00:00:00     
    updates       | 3.4 kB  00:00:03     
    Package freeglut-2.8.1-3.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
    Nothing to do
    [root@devmaster gym]#

Comment: Install glut means `sudo apt install freeglut3-dev`. ... GL and GLU libs : `apt install libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev`

Comment: In centos 6.5 system, there are no free glut 3 - dev, libgl 1 - mesa - dev, libglu 1 - mesa - dev packages, which are all in Ubuntu system.

Comment: I have a RHEL 7.4 (mostly CentOS 7.5) and I can find `freeglut-devel` packages. I have those installed and I could run your code (it crashs after a moment, but it "works")

Comment: Daniel Rodríguez, I have installed freeglut-devel packages. Now the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 17):

For whoever stumbles on this question the solution is to install `freeglut-devel` package for your OS distribution:

```
# apt systems - Ubuntu, Debian
apt install freeglut-devel
# yum - Centos
yum -y install freeglut-devel
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04:
`apt install freeglut3-dev`

Comment: On Arch, I installed the [glu](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/glu/) package, `pacman -S glu`.

Comment: Thanks @JacquesKvam---`pacman -S freeglut` doesn't seem to be enough.  I needed `glu`.

Comment: The solution from @Fons worked for me, I'm using UBUNTU and WSL2.

Answer (score 4):

For raspberry pi zero with Linux DietPi 4.19.97+ #1294 armv6l GNU/Linux:

`sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev`

Answer (score 3):

Note: To someone who comes wandering in and can't find a solution on Linux. First, install the following:

```
sudo apt install freeglut3-dev freeglut3 libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxext-dev libxt-dev
sudo apt install python3-opengl libgl1-mesa-glx libglu1-mesa
```

Secondly, if you're using PyCharm flatpak don't use that. Download directly from the website. For some reason executing python programs from the flatpak version fails to find the relevant OpenGL libraries (As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52909744/4699994))