# Pyglet fails to load GLU library

Tags: python, opengl, pycharm, pyglet

My pyglet application fails to run, only giving the error `ImportError: Library "GLU" not found.` I have installed PyOpenGL and libgl1 across the system, in the virtualenv, and tried reinstalling everything multiple times. Nothing seems to help. Similiar questions mention it may be related to my graphics card, which is `Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)`. Anyone have any ideas?

Further details

- Python version: 3.7
- IDE: Pycharm Community
- OS: elementaryOS v5.0 Juno
- Installation method: Flatpak
- Graphics Driver: `Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics`

Comment: Answers are given below, not in the actual question.

Comment: You should probably mention which graphics drivers you've installed. For instance, `mesa`? `x86-video-intel`? And if this is a **pycharm** package you're trying to use, tag it as such. Because Pyglet nad Pycharm are two separate things.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I wasn't sure what the problem was when I was writing the question. Through preliminary googling I found that most arrows pointed towards pyglet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't install pycharm through flatpak, for whatever reason that doesn't work. Install it through the pycharm website.

Comment: Can't believe this was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely missing developer packages of `freeglut`.

look for `freeglut-devel` in your OS package manager:

```
sudo apt install freeglut-devel
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately that didn't seem to work, I installed both `freeglut3` and `freeglut3-dev` but it had no affect. Does it matter that my python is a virtualenv?